Directus extension: Cannot find package 'ssh2'
I have created the directus extension and now calling ssh2 package in it.
Getting this error when I am running backend server:
Cannot find package 'ssh2' imported from /directus/extensions/mappingakeneo/dist/index.js
However I have installed SSH2 package in root, api and extension directory.
SSH2 package import solution
